# FileContentResult return excel file corrupt

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, vue-component, filecontentresult

I am trying to download an xlsx file from an ftp but when I download and try to open it I get that it is a corrupt file. . I share the back and front code.

```
public async Task<TransacResult> DownloadFileInterface(Uri serverUri, string fileName)
    {
        StreamReader sr;
        byte[] fileContent;
        try
        {
            string ftpUser = GetConfiguration()["SuatKeys:FTPSuatUser"];
            string ftpPassword = GetConfiguration()["SuatKeys:FTPSuatPassword"];

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
            sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            var fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(fileContent, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                FileDownloadName = fileName + ".xlsx"
            };
            return new TransacResult(true, fileContentResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new TransacResult(false, new Message("SUAT-ERR-C02", MessageCategory.Error, "Conexión rechazada", ex.Message));
        }
    }

async downloadlayout() {
    var obj = this.interfaces.item;
    if (this.$store.state.usuarioActivo.modeD == 0)
      obj = serialize(obj);
    const res = await this.$store.dispatch("apiPost", {
      url: "Interface/DownloadDinamycLayout",
      item: obj
    })
    console.clear();
    console.log(res);
    const a = document.createElement("a"); 
    a.href = "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64," + res.fileContents; 
    a.download = res.fileDownloadName;
    a.click(); 
    a.remove();
},
```

reading the file does not present any problem
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you the file on FTP isn't corrupted, the problem have is that .xlsx files are not textual files, but `StreamReader` is intended for reading text. Using it as you are will corrupt arbitrary binary data (e.g. an .xlsx file).

I would personally just stream the file from FTP, through your server, and straight to the client:

```cs
public async Task<TransacResult> DownloadFileInterface(Uri serverUri, string fileName)
{
    StreamReader sr;
    byte[] fileContent;
    try
    {
        string ftpUser = GetConfiguration()["SuatKeys:FTPSuatUser"];
        string ftpPassword = GetConfiguration()["SuatKeys:FTPSuatPassword"];

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
        
        Stream ftpFileStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        var fileContentResult = new FileStreamResult(ftpFileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileName + ".xlsx"
        };
        return new TransacResult(true, fileContentResult);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new TransacResult(false, new Message("SUAT-ERR-C02", MessageCategory.Error, "Conexión rechazada", ex.Message));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue. Turns out, if you're using certain middleware for logging, it forces the stream to be converted to a text representation which is incompatible with Excel. The only work-around I have is to not use the middleware.

I found this out on this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3304

Answer (score -1):

I tried three times with two Actions:

```
[HttpPost]
        public FileResult download(IFormFile file)
        {
            var filestream = file.OpenReadStream(); 
            var filestreamreader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.Default);          
            var fileContent1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(filestreamreader.ReadToEnd());
            return File(fileContent1, "application/ms-excel", "3.xlsx");
            
        }

[HttpPost]
        public FileResult download1(IFormFile file)
        {
            var filestream = file.OpenReadStream();
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(filestream);
            var fileContent = package.GetAsByteArray();
            return File(fileContent, "application/ms-excel", "3.xlsx");
        }
```

At First,I tried to read the content of txt file and xlsx file ,you could see we could get the content string of txt file,but failed to get the  string in xlsx file

Then I tried to get the content byte from stream again with EPPlus and succeeded
The ResulT:

The reason I recomanded EEplus: If Oneday  we want to download the xlsx file with some extra infomation,we could just add some codes rather than delet the codes and write again
codes as below；

```
[HttpPost]
        public FileResult download1(IFormFile file)
        {
            var employeelist = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee(){Id=1,Name="Jhon",Gender="M",Salary=5000},
                new Employee(){Id=2,Name="Graham",Gender="M",Salary=10000},
                new Employee(){Id=3,Name="Jenny",Gender="F",Salary=5000}
            };
            
            var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
            
             
            byte[] fileContent;
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
            {
                // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Employee");
                
                //Set the Width and Height
                //worksheet.Column(1).Width = xx;
                //worksheet.Row(1).Height = xx;
                
                //Add the headers

                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Name";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Gender";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Salary (in $)";
                for(int i=0; i< employeelist.Count; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = employeelist[i].Id;
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = employeelist[i].Name;
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = employeelist[i].Gender;
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = employeelist[i].Salary;
                } 
                package.Save(); //Save the workbook.
                fileContent = package.GetAsByteArray();
            }            
            return File(fileContent, "application/ms-excel", "target.xlsx");
        }
```

The Result:
[image]

Comment: _"you could not directly transfer th stream to filecontent"_ - why not? If the FTP server contains an .xlsx file, then you should be able to stream those bytes straight through ASP.NET Core and out to the client. I don't really see how this answers the question. If what you are saying were true, you wouldn't even be able to download an XLSX file from an FTP server, let alone manipulate it before sending it to the client.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar xlsx file is different from csv and txt file ,So we could not  just use Streamreader to get the filecontent.The code I showed yesterday  is  about hwo to get the   content  byte with third-part tool like EPPLus

Comment: Sure, we can't use `StreamReader`, which is for reading text from a `Stream`, but nothing would stop you doing something like `return new FileStreamResult(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileDownloadName = fileName + ".xlsx" }`, which you have implied isn't possible. There is absolutely no need to involve EPPlus to simply stream the file from FTP->Client through the ASP.NET Core server.

Comment: Can you at least explain why you think that EPPlus is required here? What does it add (working within the bounds of your answer) over something like [this](https://pastebin.com/C8kvVc4t) where we can just copy the bytes to a `MemoryStream`? And what if OP needs to transfer a video file next? Or an executable?

Comment: @ DiplomacyNotWar Yes,wo could copy  the file without EPPlus here,but since OP has claimed this api is designed to download xlsx, so we don't need to consider other types.

Comment: My point is that you're adding another dependency, another thing to update, another thing that could have bugs in its own implementation, for no benefit whatsoever. Why?

Comment: If we handle the stream with EEPlus, One day we want to download the xlsx file with some extra infomation,we could just add some codes rather than delet the codes and write again

Comment: I see. I suppose there's some sense to that.